# How do I use the F# Reflection library?

Tags: reflection, f#

I am trying to follow this example (from p137 of Rob Pickering's ["Foundations of F#"](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590597576) book) but I can't get it to work with the latest F# CTP.

I appear to be missing the definition of 'Value' on the 3rd line where it does

```
Value.GetInfo(x)
```

This generates :

> **error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Value' is not defined.**

Can anyone tell me where this is coming from or what the new syntax is if this is now done differently? (be gentle - this is my first play with F#)

Here's the example I am working from:-

```
#light
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let printTupleValues x =
    match Value.GetInfo(x) with
    | TupleValue vals ->
    print_string "("
    vals
    |> List.iteri
        (fun i v ->
            if i <> List.length vals - 1 then
                Printf.printf " %s, " (any_to_string v)
            else
                print_any v)
    print_string " )"
    | _ -> print_string "not a tuple"

printTupleValues ("hello world", 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The F# reflection library was rewritten for either Beta 1 or the CTP.  Here is your code slightly changed to use the new library, and to avoid using the F# PlusPack (print_string is for OCaml compatibility).

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let printTupleValues x =
    if FSharpType.IsTuple( x.GetType() ) then
        let s =
            FSharpValue.GetTupleFields( x )
            |> Array.map (fun a -> a.ToString())
            |> Array.reduce (fun a b -> sprintf "%s, %s" a b)
        printfn "(%s)" s
    else 
        printfn "not a tuple"

printTupleValues ("hello world", 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you prefer using match to decompose the tuple, then try this using an active pattern.  Advantage is you can add support for additional types pretty easily.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let (|ParseTuple|_|) = function
    | o when FSharpType.IsTuple( o.GetType() ) ->
        Some( FSharpValue.GetTupleFields(o) )
    | _ -> None

let printTupleValues = function
    | ParseTuple vals ->
        let s =
            vals
            |> Array.map (fun a -> a.ToString())
            |> Array.reduce (fun a b -> sprintf "%s, %s" a b)
        printfn "(%s)" s
    | _ ->
        printf "not a tuple"

printTupleValues ("hello world", 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether your function has been renamed or removed in the current F# versions.
You should take a look at `FSharp.Reflection` in your IDE's object explorer to check that and maybe read [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Reflection#Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection_Namespace).